# Is there a maximum number of suffixes that can be added to an English word?

Tags: suffixes, linguistics, morphology

You can add various [derivational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix#Derivational_suffixes) and [inflectional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix#Inflectional_suffixes) suffixes on to most English words to create new longer words (or forms of words). But is there a definite or theoretical maximum that can be added in the case of English? If not is there rough upper limit in typical vocabulary?

Trying to think of examples the best I can come up with off the top of my head is:

> *ego + ist + ic + al + ly*
>
> egoistically

Comment: Would decid-ed-ly be one?

Comment: @mplungjan: Of course, but it only has two suffixes. I'm pretty sure more than four is possible but they're not easy to think up.

Comment: In your example, I think it's slightly unfair to count "ic" and "al" as two suffixes: the "al" is in effect necessary when you add "ly" to "ic". (And this shows a slight problem in counting affixes generally; how fair is it also to count "en-" and "-en" in "enliven"?)

Comment: Theoretical? No. You can keep adding *-ize*, *-ation*, *-al*, rinse-repeat, ad infinitum. So, whenever someone brings up a word such as [antidisestablishmentarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antidisestablishmentarianism), you can raise them an antidisestablishmentarianization, antidisestablishmentarianizational, antidisestablishmentarianizationalize, antidisestablishmentarianizationalization, etc. (Same with prefixes. You could go antidisantidisantidis... for quite some time.) There is merely a *practical* limit — which likely differs from person to person.

Comment: @Neil: It's a linguistics question not a moral one so I don't know who I'd be fair or unfair to. In fact I'm interested in agglutinative languages right now so I'm trying to hone my knowledge of English morphology as well so I can better compare. I could change the question to "suffixed morphemes" if you really think it would help.

Comment: @RegDwight: Yes I was pretty sure there were some groups of suffixes which could lead to loops but at the time I couldn't think of any. So I think they're worth mentioning and then excluding as an interesting special case unless we can find any generally accepted English word that does have circular morphemes.

Comment: No, your description is fine. I didn't realise that when people talked about a "fair" test/count they meant a morally justifiable one...!

Comment: RegDwight - interesting point I forgot to mention in my answer. Have added a corresponding paragraph.

Comment: @Neil: I guess it depends on whether you think a higher count or a lower count is a better or worse one. For my purposes it seems each is a morpheme and I'm looking for high numbers but both analyses seem to be justifiable alternatives.

Comment: Yes, in terms of counting morphemes, I agree-- it's more something to be aware of/mention, that counting morphemes doesn't necessarily mean counting 'free variation' in the number of possible combinations. I think you'll find a similar phenomenon in your analysis of agglutinating languages.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is a hardcoded limit and it's probably 32 or 64. SCNR.

Comment: @Neil, I wouldn't say _-al_ is required to form adverbs from _-ic_ adjectives. It's very common, sure, but what of ‘publicly’, ‘frantic(al)ly’, etc.? In some cases it's optional; and in some it's not even allowed.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's not required in all cases, but however you characterise the condition, the point is that there's an interaction between the two affixes "al" and "ly". (FWIW I think this particular word is one of a class where the "al" is necessary with "ly", though it being 100% necessary isn't  crucial to my overall point.)

Comment: By my count_antidisestablishmentarianistically_ has (at least vestigially) six suffixes (-ary, -an, -ist, -ic, -al, and -ly) along with two prefixes (anti- and dis-). Now if only we could fins occasions for using it...

Answer (score 12):

I think you can get a rough idea by grouping affixes according to their rough function and assuming that people wouldn't tend to form words with two affixes of a similar function (e.g. it would be rare to make a word with both "bi-" and "tri-", because they both denote conflicting numbers).

Crystal (Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language) suggests the following categories for what he sees as the 57 "common prefixes in English" (without giving exact criteria):

- negation ("dis-", "in-")
- reversal ("de-")
- disparaging ("mal-")
- size/degree ("arch-", "sub-")
- orientation ("anti-", "contra-")
- location/distance ("extra-", "intra-")
- time/order ("ex-", "pre-")
- number ("bi-", "uni-")
- grammatical conversion

So as a rough guess, we could say that the upper limit on *prefixes* was roughly one prefix from each of these categories.

As far as suffixes, adapting also from a list of common ones suggested by Crystal, we might suggest that it would be rare to have more than one from each of the following categories in a single word:

- abstract noun markers ("-dom", "-hood")
- concrete noun/"agent" markets ("-ster", "-eer", "-ist")
- word category markers ("-ly", "-ate", "-ify")
- noun derivation from verb/adjective ("-age", "-ity")
- inflection/adjective derivation from noun/verb ("-less", "-able")

It's more difficult to combine suffixes because of their tendency to change the word class. As a rough guage of the limit on suffixation, maybe we could say it is around 4 (the first three of these categories, plus one instance of word category "derivation", although occasionally you will get 2 of the latter combined).

So as an "absolute upper limit that would apply in 99% of cases", a sensible conjecture on the basis of the above would be around 13.

On the other hand, if you take a word such as "pseudo/anti/dis/establish/ment/arian/ist/ic/ally" with 8 (or 9 if you include the automatically necessary "al") affixes, this appears intuitively to be reaching the upper end of what is practical...

**Update:** I should also concur that *theoretically* you can find corner cases where there is no upper limit. Certain prefixes can themselves be repeated. If you can "re-do" something, you can also "re-re-do" it etc. If I'm an anti-abortionist, somebody who doesn't agree with me is an anti-anti-abortionist, and somebody disagreeing with their philosophy is an anti-anti-anti-abortionist. In music, there is an interesting pattern of nomenclature for short notes ("semiquaver", "demisemiquaver", "hemidemisemiquaver", "semihemidemisemiquaver"...). Suffixes which don't change the word category of the derived word (or combinations which change it back and forth) are also potential candidates. "Loneliness" is the concept of being lonely; "Lonelinessless" is a lack of loneliness; "Lonelinesslessness" is the concept of there being a lack of loneliness etc. The nomenclature of chemicals involves a whole system of affixes that can theoretically be used to name compounds of infinite complexity using "words" of infinite length.

Comment: I appreciate the inclusion of prefixes in your answer but I was specifically asking about suffixes only rather than all adfixes and your summing-up seems to answer for total morphemes or total adfixes.

Comment: OK, I think it would be quite rare to have more than one from each of the 5 suffix classes listed above (and as I say, probably the last 2 can be merged in you have 4 classes for the sake of most words). But I suppose with those 4/5 classes in mind it would be worth playing around and seeing how easily you come up with exceptions.

Comment: Hmm, we need to see if our streets are extraneighbourhoodifiable :)

Comment: @Neil: I didn't want to include chemical nomenclature for the same reasons that dictionaries like the OED don't include them. They are as much if not more formulae than words.

Comment: Yes, you could argue that way. Although, note that unlike 'normal' equations they're more readily prefixed by determiners and pluralised. In many cases, I think you can also argue that they contain a "head" morpheme. If you argue against counting chemical names, then you could use similar reasoning to argue that the 'formulaic' words such as "lonelinesslessness', 'antidisestablishmentarianificationarianificationarian' and 'hemidemisemihemidemisemiquaver' are also 'formulae' rather than 'words', thus negating the idea that affixes can be combined infinitely... :)

Comment: Antidisestablishmentarianism and most other contenders for longest English word are regularly criticised as not being read words on this basis despite some making it into some dictionaries.

Comment: Well, it's all arbitrary. There's no God-given definition of "real word" (or indeed "word")-- it's all a question of the arbitrary criteria that specific editors decide on. Some dictionaries do include chemical formulae (presumably what they see as the more common/commercially interesting ones), whilst others may well decide that "antidisestablishmentarianism" is never actually used except in discussions about the longest word of English.

Comment: It would be nice to hear from some people with some linguistics background too for their perspective.

Comment: (I have 2 degrees in linguistics for what it's worth and I'm also the compiler of a dictionary, so I have a vaaague idea about this kind of thing.)

Comment: @Neil: You should've mentioned. Your comments didn't sound so technical so I assumed you were a typical EL&U'er (-: