# Suffixes -hood -dom -ness... Is there any rule?

Tags: nouns, suffixes

English is not my mother tongue, hence I wonder if there was any rule to choose one suffix from another. For now, I use more of a it-sounds-better-than-the-other kind of rule.

i.e: Why *freedom, kingdom, childhood, brotherhood, uniqueness, likeliness*?

Comment: See Neil Coffey's fine article [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-suffixes-that-can-be-added-to-an-english-word/32717#32717) for starters (actually Crystal did the original work).

Comment: I think there's no rule. Also, *likeliness* is the same as *likelihood*, which is way more common.

Comment: I would upvote both of you if I could

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in a posting mood. Here's a comment on the semantics of the suffix -hood from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-hood), which I didn't realise was so thorough:

> **-hood**
>
> A condition or state of being the thing or being in the role denoted
>   by the word it is suffixed to, usually a noun.
>
> child - childhood
>
> A group sharing a specified condition or state.
>
> brother - brotherhood
>   neighbor - neighborhood

You can try the others yourself.