# In word construction, is there an affix order?

Tags: suffixes, syntactic-analysis, prefixes, affixes

Does English have classes of prefixes and suffixes like it does adjectives, and if so, how are they usually ordered?

For example, adjectives usually go in this order (or something like it):

- Quantity / Number
- Opinion (e.g. *beautiful*, *stupid*)
- Size
- Shape
- Condition (e.g. *soggy, warm*)
- Age
- Color, Pattern, etc.
- Proper adjectives (Place of origin, nationalities)
- Material
- Purpose

So you might have three beautiful large square peeling old bright Portuguese oil paintings for hanging on walls.

Is there something similar with affixes?

Comment: I think the answer is 'in a way," but I think it has more to do with the specific affixes and less to do with the semantic meaning of them. For example, the nominalizing suffix "-ness" can be applied after the adjective-creating suffix "-less," but generally not the other war around. Another example: negative prefixes generally aren't preceded by any other prefixes,

Comment: Somewhat related question: [Is there a maximum number of suffixes that can be added to an English word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-suffixes-that-can-be-added-to-an-english-word?rq=1)